# Changing Opening Hours without affecting historic data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I've been tasked to create a data visualisation dashboard that relies on me drilling into the existing database.

One report is 'revenue per available covers' - part of the calculation determining how many hours were booked against how many hours were available.

The problem is the 'hours available', currently this is stored in a schedule table that has a 1-1 link with the venue - and if admin want to update this there is a simple CRUD panel with the pre-linked field ready to complete.

I have realised that if I rely on this table at any point in the future when the schedule changes the calculations change for any historic data.

Any ideas on how to keep a 'historic' schedule with as minimum impact as possible to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a (potentially) slowly-changing dimension.  Basically, there are two approaches:

- For each transactional record, include the hours that you are interested in.
- Store the schedule with time frames, which capture the schedule at a particular point in time.

In SQL Server, I would normally go for the second option, using `effDate` and `endDate` columns to capture the period when the schedule is active.

I would suggest that you start with a deeper explanation of the concept, such as the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) page.